# Developing a non english language Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I need to develop a multi language sharepoint site, (English / French ) for example.
I installed the french language pack with Service packs.
I used variations, added labels for En-US and Fr-FR and created the hierarchies.
The problem is that when working with the french site, All Sharepoint menu items are in french. This is very hard for the team to work with the french menus and text.
Is there any way i can have sharepoint menus still in english while working on a non-english variations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the language of a site after it is created is not really supported, but I did find [this blog post](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/mirjam/archive/2008/04/29/changing-the-language-of-an-existing-sharepoint-site.aspx) that tells you how to do it by cracking open the DB (I do not recommend this approach).

The better option is to delete your French variation and then recreate it.  When you create the label be sure to leave the English language selected.  This tells SharePoint what language pack to use when creating the site.

Comment: Won't creating the label with English language selected have any side-effects? for example, displaying sharepoint messages in English in the French site? or having some problems with reading resources files, in RTL languages for example?

Comment: Yup, it sure will.  But, your menu settings will be in English.

Comment: Additionally you will miss all the locale settings you might want to use to format dates, currency, etc. If you're developing a multilanguage site I'd suggest you stick with the variations and their locale.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at our solution to replace the variataions in SharePoint.

http://www.alphamosaik.com/Pages/Solutions_EN_MultilingualModule.aspx

regards

Edgard